# limit fixed number of rows from a fixed number of categories

Tags: mysql

For simplictiy sake, i will leave the fields which aren't relevant to the problem.

My table structure is,

**News**

`news_id | parent_category | child_category`

**category**

`category_id | maincategory_name`

**subcategory**

`subcategory_id | subcategory_name`

As it is already evident, `category_id` is linked to `parent_id` and `subcategory_id` is linked to `child_category` of the `news` table.

---

**What I have right now**

```
SELECT * 
 FROM (

       SELECT news . * , @rn := 
       CASE WHEN @child_category = child_category
       THEN @rn +1
       ELSE 1 
       END AS rn, @child_category := child_category
       FROM news, (

                   SELECT @rn :=0, @child_category := NULL
                   ) AS vars
                       ORDER BY child_category
                   ) AS T1

                        LEFT JOIN category ON parent_category = category.category_id
                        LEFT JOIN subcategory ON child_category =  
                        subcategory.subcategory_id
                        WHERE rn <=12 AND parent_category = (SELECT category_id FROM 
                        category WHERE maincategory_name='ukraine') AND 
                        child_category!= (SELECT `subcategory_id` FROM subcategory 
                        WHERE `subcategory_name` = 'kiev')
                        ORDER BY category.category_id DESC
```

The above sql works and fetches 12 rows from each category.

**The problem**
The problem i am facing now is, the query fetches data from every category. And I want to limit this category number to 2 or 3. e.g. If there is 8 subcategories in `subcategory` table, it'l fetch data from all of them. And I want to limit the fetching to a limit say, 3(any 3 categories).

I tried using an `IN` statement as in following,

```
SELECT * 
     FROM (

       SELECT news . * , @rn := 
       CASE WHEN @child_category = child_category
       THEN @rn +1
       ELSE 1 
       END AS rn, @child_category := child_category
       FROM news, (

                   SELECT @rn :=0, @child_category := NULL
                   ) AS vars
                       ORDER BY child_category
                   ) AS T1

                        LEFT JOIN category ON parent_category = category.category_id
                        LEFT JOIN subcategory ON child_category =  
                        subcategory.subcategory_id
                        WHERE rn <=12 AND parent_category = (SELECT category_id FROM 
                        category WHERE maincategory_name='ukraine') AND 
                        child_category IN (2,4)
                        ORDER BY category.category_id DESC
```

where the `IN range` will be retrieve by a subquery. In logic, if i limit that subquery to 3 results, my job is done.  But as it turns out, `IN` statement doesn't support `LIMIT` clause within subquery.

So question is, what is a workaround on retrieving the datas (fixed but that i already figured out) from **limited number of categories**.

---

**sameple data**

News Table

```
| news_id | parent_category | child_category
|   1     |       1         |     1
|   2     |       1         |     2
```

Category Table

```
| category_id | maincategory_name
|      1      |      Ukraine
|      2      |      Russia
|      3      |      Belarus
```

subcategory table

```
| subcategory_id | subcategory_name
|        1       |     Kiev
|        2       |     Odessa
|        3       |     Moscow
|        4       |     Simferopol
|        5       |     Dnipropetrovsk
```

The result should be like this.....

Suppose Kiev, Odessa, simferopol and Dnipropetrovsk goes to maincategory 1 i.e. Ukraine and I want 2 categories **excluding Kiev** (i.e. result should contain either *simferopol* and *Dnipro* or *Odessa* and *Dnipro* or *Odessa* and *simferopol* )

The problem is, query will fetch all the 3 categories (or more if available) where as i want only 2 (or 3 at times).

**FURTHER INFO**

---

*sql fiddle*

```
create table News(news_id int, parent_category int, child_category int);
insert into News values (1,1,1), (2,1,2), (3,1,2), (4,1,4),(5,1,4), (6,1,5), (7,2,3), (8,1,5), (9,1,2);
create table Category(category_id int, maincategory_name varchar(100));
insert into Category values (1, 'Ukraine'), (2, 'Russia'), (3, 'Belarus');
create table Subcategory (subcategory_id int, subcategory_name varchar(100));
insert into Subcategory values (1, 'Kiev'), (2, 'Odessa'), (3, 'Moscow'), (4, 'Simferopol'), (5, 'Dinipro');
```

*sample data*

[image]

**GOAL**

From the above result I want to achieve the following:

- Fetch result only from one main category (i.e. Ukraine here and remove the russia) but it can be easily done so no worries on that part.
- Fetch Only 2 subcategories (Above set contains 3 subcategories. Odessa, simferopol and Dnipro. I want only any two of them). I can hardcode it to retreive it but i will be using this same query in other places too so hardcoding will defeat that purpose.
- From each of the above 2 subcategories fetched above, maximum 5 rows should be obtained from each subcategory. (I have achieved that in the 1st query in my question).

From above 2 requirements, i have achieved no. 1 and no. 3. Where i am stuck is at number2.
From the result set, i am unable to fetch the result containing only 2 subcategories.
and result set outputs datas containinig all the categories available. (here, only 3 subcategories so result contains all the 3. If there will be 10 subcat, it will retrieve all the 10 subcat data). I hope now a bit more clear now.

Comment: @tombom more info added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I may still don't get what you want. Why don't you simply use a `GROUP BY`?

```
/* SELECT * FROM ( */
SELECT 
n.news_id,
c.maincategory_name,
sc.subcategory_name
FROM
News n
INNER JOIN Category c ON n.parent_category = c.category_id
INNER JOIN Subcategory sc ON n.child_category = sc.subcategory_id
WHERE maincategory_name = 'Ukraine'
GROUP BY maincategory_name, subcategory_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
/* )q1 INNER JOIN with_whatever ON q1.news_id = with_whatever.Id */
```

The table `with_whatever` holds the data from which you want to get "maximum 5 rows should be obtained from each subcategory". Your sample data still doesn't reflect that. That's why I'm unsure, if it's what you're asking for.

Comment: I guess i am not able to explain it in a clear manner. I appreciate your effort. To make it simpler, can you run my 2nd query in the question in the fiddle? that's the exact result i want. Only problem is, inside that `IN` statement, the `(2,4)` should come from a subquery (From the subcategory table with referece to parentCategory) and not hardcoded. But the my subquery returns not only 2 but all the subcat that is available under the parent cat. I am unable to put a limit to 2 results inside that `IN` subquery.

Comment: @itachi And why 2 and 4? What's the criteria for that?

Comment: 2 and 4 refers to the subcategory_id in the subcategory table. The criteria is to select any 2 subcategories which falls under the main category. But each subcategory has one to many relationship with the main category table. Hence, main category needs to be specify each time.... I guess this approach has some troublesome areas. May be i need to rethink the design again....

Comment: You want the subcategory to be distinct, right? So I just added an `ORDER BY RAND()` so you don't get the same result over and over again. Then I don't see why my answer shouldn't be correct. Or I'm a bit retarded and really don't understand the question :)